# Can't change terminal colors for prompts in Ubuntu on Windows Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, windows-terminal, fish

I run Ubuntu with fish using wsl on Windows Terminal. I have color scheme configured correctly and it seems that all the colors are changed except for the prompt colors. It remains red on typing and blue when command is recognized like it was before applying the scheme.

[image]

With color scheme:

[image]

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `fish` is using RGB or 256-color sequences to colorize the command once it has been typed. The terminal emulator doesn't really have a say in changing those colors when emitted by a CLI application.

I'd double check your `fish` configuration. Anything that looks like `\x1b[38;2;255;0;255m` or `\x1b[38;5;135m` are RGB or 256  color sequences the Terminal can't affect.